# Cut Property does not hold for $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

**Cut Property**: If $A, B$ are nonempty, disjoint sets with $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}$ and $a < b$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \leq c$ whenever $x \in A$ and $x \geq c$ whenever $x \in B$.

The author of my text notes that, since the Cut Property is equivalent to the Axiom of Completeness, one can use the Cut Property as the fundamental axiom that distinguishes $\mathbb{R}$ from $\mathbb{Q}$. I want to find an example of partitions $A, B$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ that shows that the Cut Property is invalid when $\mathbb{R}$ is replaced by $\mathbb{Q}$.

A partition like $A = (-\infty,1/2]$ and $B = (1/2,\infty)$ seems to work just fine (in this case $c = 1/2$). I can't think of a partition that looks essentially different from this example and would appreciate any tips.

Comment: Rationals less than $\sqrt{2}$, greater than $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

As in  André Nicolas's comment, try $A = (-\infty, 0) \cup \{x \ge 0 : x^2 \le 2\}$ and $B = \{x \ge 0 : x^2 > 2\}$.

Show that if such a number $c$ existed, we would have $c^2 = 2$.  But there is no rational number for which this is true.